# OpenCart Auto-complete CMS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, opencart, dropdown

I'm currently developing a site in OpenCart for a client of mine and they are having issues adding filters and categories to products. When they try to add a category by typing in the category name, it sometimes does not show up. If it does show up and they click on it, it sometimes does not detect that it has been clicked and does not add it (despite clicking it multiple times).

Another thing my client does not like about this, is that when they forget what categories they have or what names of them are, they do not have any way of choosing them. It would be good if there was maybe a dropdown list or a select input

```
<select multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Has anyone had these issues before and if so how did they fix them?

***Edit***
Sorry forgot to mention I'm using Version 2.0.3.1 of OpenCart.

Answer (score -1):

If your opencart is multi-language you can search only with the selected language in the admin area. 
Empty category names in search means empty category name/title for the selected language.

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question. I am not saying I cannot find the categories when searching I am saying it is hard to remember what they have been called. Also the site is single language